# Error accessing spreadsheet: Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I put a error handling try catch block in my script and I get the error

> Error accessing spreadsheet: Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1MUzlo-K5eNMHOa28kme0MG8JiSatV9Ia.

All the permissions for the file appears to be correct and the id is correct. It appears to fail on this line

> var excelFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(driveFile.getId());.

Comment: Kindly share your entire script

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]